# Can not remove folder in program files directory. Changing permissions doesn't work

Tags: windows, installation, permissions, uninstall, privileges

I was installing [CoDeSys](https://www.codesys.com/). I downloaded the installer executable file, which seems to be a MSI installer. Followed the steps in the installer window, and at the very last step a progress bar is shown. The bar got filled to the end, and remained full. The installer remained in this state for an hour with the progress at 100%.

There was no message shown or something else like the installer wizard that closes. I waited and then opened the installed program CoDeSys, and it worked all as it should be.

Then I closed the installer window and confirmed to stop. This was stupid because the wizard started to rollback all changes and started to remove the application...

Now when I retry running the installer wizard, it says the folder *CODESYS 3.5.15.20* in *Program Files* should be empty. But it isn't. It still contains some remnants of the previous installation that was undone. I don't see CoDeSys in my list of installed programs, so I cannot remove it from there since it is actually already removed as I said. 
When I just go to my program files folder, and manually remove the *CODESYS 3.5.15.20* folder from there, I always get a message saying the folder can not be removed/changed because I need permission from SYSTEM.

Tried several solutions from the internet, like changing the owner/permissions of the folder. But even when I am the owner (and not system or something else), I get no control over the folder. Changing the owner of the folder to myself ('Sam'), and retrying to delete it, displays the message: I need permission from 'Sam'.

- My operating system is Windows 10.
- I don't see any uninstall executable in the files stayed behind.

Comment: “I always get a message saying the folder can not be removed/changed because I need permission from SYSTEM.” - As the built-in Administrator account change the ACL for that single folder then delete it.

Comment: *It still contains some remnants of the previous installation that was undone.* - You may be able to delete these elements manually from the folder without removing the folder itself.

Comment: @Anaksunaman I already tried this to make the folder empty. But doesn't work. I didn't mention this in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using cmd as administrator.

Use the command `rmdir /s /q C:/Program Files/CODESYS 3.5.15.20`, assuming that's the correct file path.

Answer (score 0):

One option to attempt a removal or rename of a file or directory is to use the Pending File Rename Operating (PFRO) functionality of Windows. This will perform the action:

- At the next restart.
- As the local system user.
- Early at system start to minimize a process holding a handle to the item.

To do so, you can manually create or update the `REG_MULTI_SZ` `PendingFileRenameOperations` registry value under the registry key `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager` to be read by the Windows Session Manager (SMSS.exe) at start-up.  The easiest way is to use a tool to create or append to the value if it already exists.

One option is [movefile.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/pendmoves) from Sysinternals/Microsoft.

As an example, to remove the folder `C:\testdelete` on the next system restart, run in an elevated prompt:
`movefile.exe "C:\testdelete" ""`

The above command will create or append to, the `REG_MULTI_SZ` `PendingFileRenameOperations` registry value under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager` as shown below:

[image: PFRO key example]

**Note**: The entries in the value are processed in pairs such that a blank line following an item will instruct the SMSS.exe process to delete the previous item. If the proceeding line has a path then it will be renamed.

If there are issues removing the directory or any of the operations carried out, they will be logged to C:\windows\pfro.log